# Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes() does not update "updated_at"

Tags: product

I have the following code:

```
$storeId = 1;
$attributesData = array("price" => $data['price'], 'updated_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')
    ->updateAttributes(array($data['product_id']), $attributesData, $storeId);
```

When I run this code, the price is updated but the `updated_at column` in `catalog_product_entity` is not (it does this regardless of update_at being in `$attributesData`).

I know I could just hammer in a quick little update query to update the date myself (and I will if I have to), but that is not the "Magento" way of doing things. I also do not want to load up the entire model just to save it. That would defeat the entire purpose of using what I call the "fast way" of updating products.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

I think it's because `updated_at` is a static attribute not a 'variable' EAV attribute. You can't save it as you did. You have to save it with the help of the Product model.

`Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Action::updateAttributes()` call the method of the resource model `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Action::updateAttributes()` and in this method tries to get the attribute from the eav entity. But in the case of `updated_at`, it saves the attribute in a bad way. See below.

I tried your code and got an exception, I use Magento 1.5. You probably also have a silenced error. After debuggging, I saw the following sql query which is triggered when using your code:

```
INSERT INTO `mage_catalog_product_entity` (`entity_type_id`, `attribute_id`, `store_id`, `entity_id`, `value`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `value`=VALUES(`value`)


0   (string:1) 4    
1   (string:3) 498  
2   (int) 0 
3   (int) 303   
4   (string:19) 2013-01-30 15:47:00 


SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'attribute_id' in 'field list'
```

The class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Abstract` and the method `_saveAttributeValue` show how the query is created:

```
$table   = $attribute->getBackend()->getTable();

    /**
     * If we work in single store mode all values should be saved just
     * for default store id
     * In this case we clear all not default values
     */
    if (Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
        $storeId = $this->getDefaultStoreId();
        $write->delete($table, join(' AND ', array(
            $write->quoteInto('attribute_id=?', $attribute->getAttributeId()),
            $write->quoteInto('entity_id=?', $object->getEntityId()),
            $write->quoteInto('store_id<>?', $storeId)
        )));
    }

    $bind = array(
        'entity_type_id'    => $attribute->getEntityTypeId(),
        'attribute_id'      => $attribute->getAttributeId(),
        'store_id'          => $storeId,
        'entity_id'         => $object->getEntityId(),
        'value'             => $this->_prepareValueForSave($value, $attribute)
    );
```

For me it's definitely not the way to save this attribute. Use the model instead. You will be sure of the result.